# How to proxy https requests to an http api

Tags: reactjs, server, webserver, devops

So basically I have an http Api and I can't change it to https for business reasons
and an https client that needs to stay https for the payment gateway integration and authentication
the api calls fall down due to CORS and mixed origin, I thought of two solutions

one: proxy the api calls from the client so the client will be https but the api would read its coming from http, not sure if its doable or how can I do it and need help with it

two: wrap the backend with an https api but I think that might slow the web app

which would be better ? if one, how to implement it

Comment: What possible business reasons prevent HTTPS?  Most businesses want the security.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller they are using static ips and they say that static Ips can't get an ssl certificate not sure about that as well

Comment: Your ip address has nothing to do with getting a security certificate. Certificates are tied to domain names not to IP addresses.  These days you can even host many sites with separate certificates on a single ip address.